# System.out.println print partial string when add specific variable

Tags: java

When I pass a specific variable named `number` in `System.out.println()` it print partial string.

```
change_status(senttime, data[0]);

private void change_status(String timestamp, String number){
   String query = null;
   query = "update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%"+number+"%' and sent_time > '"+timestamp+"' ";
   System.out.println("query: " + query);
}
```

Output of System.out.println is given below....

When value of data[0] is "Text" output is `update table_abc set state='2' where msg like 'Text' and sent_time > '2021-07-08 23:14:15'`

When value of data[0] is "3320112345677" output is `%' and sent_time > '2021-07-08 23:14:15'`

When value of data[0] is "1231234567" output is `%' and sent_time > '2021-07-08 23:14:15'`

**Whereas**

I need to pass data[0] variable with value "1231234567" or any other string integer value with length 10 to 12 characters.

**Question**

When System.out.println() not print complete string (sql query)  when data[0] is having string integer?

**Update**

As @Esterlinkof told that there is no issue in above mentioned snippet.
I have done little more debugging and come to know that issue is when I split that string into array and then try to print it from array.

```
String text = "1231234567
Pakistan
2021-07-08 23:14:15
11223344556677";

String[] data = null;
data = text.slipt("\n");
query = "update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%"+data[0]+"%' and sent_time > '"+data[2]+"' ";
System.out.println("query: " + query);
```

Output

```
%' and sent_time > '2021-07-08 23:14:15'
```

Whereas data[0] is having value `"1231234567"` and data[2] is `"2021-07-08 23:14:15"`

Comment: Please read about using prepared statements in Java.

Comment: I don't think that the code in its current state actually produces the output you mentioned. Could you provide more context?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You have still not provided a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Problem was with parameter of split function where was passing only `\n` like `text.slipt("\n");`

I have changed parameter from `\n` to `\\r\\n` like `text.slipt("\\r\\n");`

After that output of `System.out.println();` was correct.

Updated snippet is given below....

```
String text = "1231234567
Pakistan
2021-07-08 23:14:15
11223344556677";

String[] data = null;
data = text.slipt("\\r\\n");
query = "update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%"+data[0]+"%' and sent_time > '"+data[2]+"' ";
System.out.println("query: " + query);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code, as you can see in the result it works. Your problem is not related to print. Could you please provide more context?

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main{
        public static void main(String [] args){
                String[] data = {"Text", "3320112345677", "1231234567"};
                change_status(LocalDateTime.now().toString(), data[0]);
                change_status(LocalDateTime.now().toString(), data[1]);
                change_status(LocalDateTime.now().toString(), data[2]);
        }
        private static void change_status(String timestamp, String number){
                String query = null;
                query = "update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%"+number+"%' and sent_time > '"+timestamp+"' ";
                System.out.println("query: " + query);
        }
}
```

Result:

```
query: update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%Text%' and sent_time > '2021-07-12T11:47:11.448650'
query: update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%3320112345677%' and sent_time > '2021-07-12T11:47:11.495243'
query: update table_abc set state='2' where msg like '%1231234567%' and sent_time > '2021-07-12T11:47:11.495365'
```

Comment: you are right. I have updated code, it seems there is issue when I use split function.